# Is it true that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},e^{2i\pi/3}) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+e^{2i\pi/3})$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Is it true that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},e^{2i\pi/3}) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+e^{2i\pi/3})$? I know that $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},e^{2i\pi/3}):\mathbb{Q}]=2\times2=4$. By using WolframAlpha (cheating), I know that $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+e^{2i\pi/3}):\mathbb{Q}]=4$ as well. But this is not enough.

Comment: It is enough, if you are putting your faith in Wolfram. Always $k(\alpha+\beta) \subseteq k(\alpha,\beta)$ and you have equality of dimensions.

Comment: @Hoot Ah OK. By the way, how can I find dimension of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+e^{2i\pi/3})$ without using computer?

Comment: Zarrax gives the right answer. Do you know any Galois theory?

Comment: @Hoot : you don't define $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}]$ outside of Galois theory ?

Comment: @Hoot I just started learning it.

Comment: @Misakov: I wrote a very elementary solution proving the double inclusion in a completely algorithmic way.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio : I don't see what is elementary in your solution, since I don't understand it

Comment: @user1952009 I'm not sure what you mean. Anyway, my point was that if you know something about the Galois correspondence then you know that there's only one other intermediate field and you know what automorphism has to fix it; and it's easy to check that this element is not fixed. But usually one learns the basics of fields first, so I didn't want to assume it.

Comment: @user1952009: I simply prove that both $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{2}+\omega$ are rational functions with rational coefficients of $\alpha=\omega+\sqrt{2}$. You may skip $(2)$ and $(3)$ if not interested.

Comment: @Jack This is very cool.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio : yes this I understand, you prove explicetely how $\sqrt{2}$ is in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2} + e^{2 i \pi / 3})$, but I don't get the rest : your method for finding the minimal polynomial (or a certain polynomial) having $\alpha = \sqrt{2} + e^{2 i \pi / 3}$ as root

Comment: @user1952009: that is not crucial for your purpose, you may simply neglect it.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio : wait I think you edited, now I got it, more or less

Comment: Refs: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1504169/prove-that-sqrt35-sqrt43-is-irrational ,  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1510146/find-the-irreducible-polynomial-of-this-element-over-mathbb-q  ,  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359054/constructing-a-degree-4-rational-polynomial-satisfying-f-sqrt2-sqrt3-0

Comment: $\sqrt{2}+e^{2i\pi/3}$ is a primitive element of the extension. I refrain from publishing me an answer because there are enough already.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The order $ [{\mathbb Q}(\sqrt{2} + e^{2i\pi \over 3}):{\mathbb Q}]$ has to 
divide $[{\mathbb Q}(\sqrt{2},\,e^{2i\pi \over 3}):{\mathbb Q}] = 4$ since ${\mathbb Q}(\sqrt{2} + e^{2i\pi \over 3}) \subset {\mathbb Q}(\sqrt{2},\,e^{2i\pi \over 3})$. So it's either $1, 2,$ or $4$. It can't be $1$ since $\sqrt{2} + e^{2i\pi \over 3}$ is not real.

If it were $2$, there would be a quadratic polynomial with rational coefficients with $\sqrt{2} + e^{2i\pi \over 3}$ as a root. Since the coefficients are real, the complex conjugate $\sqrt{2} + e^{-{2i\pi \over 3}}$
would have to be the other root, which would mean the linear term of the polynomial would have coefficient $-2\sqrt{2} - 2 \cos{2\pi \over 3} = 
-2\sqrt{2} - 1$, which is not rational. Thus $ [{\mathbb Q}(\sqrt{2} + e^{2i\pi \over 3}):{\mathbb Q}]$ can't be $2$ either.

The only remaining 
possibility is that $ [{\mathbb Q}(\sqrt{2} + e^{2i\pi \over 3}):{\mathbb Q}]=  [{\mathbb Q}(\sqrt{2},\,e^{2i\pi \over 3}):{\mathbb Q}] = 4$. Since ${\mathbb Q}(\sqrt{2} + e^{2i\pi \over 3}) \subset {\mathbb Q}(\sqrt{2},\,e^{2i\pi \over 3})$, we therefore have ${\mathbb Q}(\sqrt{2} + e^{2i\pi \over 3}) = {\mathbb Q}(\sqrt{2},\,e^{2i\pi \over 3})$.

Answer (score 2):

Well, obviously $$\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+\omega)\subseteq\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\omega)\tag{1}$$
so we just need to prove the opposite inclusion. By expanding the LHS of the following identity
$$ (\alpha-\sqrt{2})^3 = \omega^3=1 \tag{2} $$
through the binomial theorem we get:
$$ \sqrt{2} = \frac{\alpha^3+6\alpha-1}{3\alpha^2+2},\qquad \omega=\alpha-\sqrt{2}=\frac{2\alpha^3-4\alpha-1}{3\alpha^2+2}\tag{3}$$
and that proves
$$ \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\omega)\subseteq\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)\tag{4} $$
as wanted.

Comment: " the fifth row of the last matrix is a linear combination of the previous rows, giving that $\alpha$ is a root of $z^4+2z^3-z^2-2z+7$ " needs an explanation

Comment: @user1952009: it is one of the first claim proven in linear algebra, that five non-zero vectors in $\mathbb{R}^4$ have to be linearly dependent.

Comment: lol.... no that's not what I'm asking !!!  I understand all the other answers on this page, I just don't get what reasoning you are doing for making your polynomial, and saying it is irreducible (minimal)

Comment: do You understand what you wrote ? I'm not sure, because otherwise you'd write the justifications

Comment: @user1952009: it is probably a problem you will meet very soon. Given the minimal polynomials of $\gamma$ and $\delta$, find the minimal polynomial of $\gamma+\delta$. But as already told, $(2)$ and $(3)$ are not needed to answer your question. Anyway, just replace $x$ by $\sqrt{2}$ and $y$ by $\omega$: can you get it now? $1,\sqrt{2},\omega$ and $\omega\sqrt{2}$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: I already gave you references, I do not find me compelled to fill the trivial explanations you are missing. If you do no like/understand my answer, just ignore it. And please try to be polite.

Comment: you are un-polite my friend, don't come on this forum if you don't like to explain. and the minimal polynomial of $a+b$ given we know the min.poly of $a$ and $b$ is a good hint https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant#Applications

Answer (score 2):

A different approach (assuming a bit of Galois theory).

Because $e^{2\pi i/3}=\dfrac{-1+i\sqrt3}2$ we know that $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2,e^{2\pi i/3})=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2,\sqrt{-3})$. This is a Galois extension of $\Bbb{Q}$ with a Galois group isomorphic to Klein four. The standard exercise shows that the intermediate fields are
$$
\begin{aligned}
\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2)&=\{a+b\sqrt2\mid a,b\in\Bbb{Q}\},\\
\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-3})&=\{a+b\sqrt{-3}\mid a,b\in\Bbb{Q}\},\\
\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{-6})&=\{a+b\sqrt{-6}\mid a,b\in\Bbb{Q}\}.
\end{aligned}
$$

It is easy to check that the (obvious not rational) number $\sqrt2+e^{2\pi i/3}$ is not an element of any of the above fields. Therefore it must generate the whole thing.

Answer (score 1):

It is clear that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt 2 + w) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}( \sqrt 2, w)$. We prove the other inclusion.

Since $w=-\frac12 + \frac{i\sqrt{3}}2$, we see that $\sqrt 2 + \frac{i\sqrt{3}}2\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt 2 + w)$.

Since $(\sqrt 2 + \frac{i\sqrt{3}}2)(\sqrt 2 - \frac{i\sqrt{3}}2) = 2 + \frac34 \in \mathbb{Q}$, we have $\sqrt 2 - \frac{i\sqrt{3}}2\in\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt 2 + w)$.

Adding two elements, we have $\sqrt 2 \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt 2 + w)$, and clearly $\frac{i\sqrt 3}2 \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt 2 + w)$.

Thus, we have both elements $\sqrt 2$ and $w$ are in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt 2 + w)$, thereby proving the other inclusion.

Answer (score 1):

First you have that $e^{2\pi i/3}\notin\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2)$, as $e^{2\pi i/3}$ is not real. Neither $\sqrt 2\notin\Bbb Q(e^{2\pi i/3}),$ for otherwise we would have $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2)=\Bbb Q(e^{2\pi i/3})$ as these two field extensions have degree $2$ over $\Bbb Q$.

Thus $x^2+x+1$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2)$. Hence there is an embedding $f:\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2)(e^{2\pi i/3})\rightarrow\overline{\Bbb Q}$ fixing $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2)$ with $f(e^{2\pi i/3})=e^{4\pi i/3}$. Then as $f(\sqrt 2+e^{2\pi i/3})=\sqrt 2+e^{4\pi i/3}$, we get that $\sqrt 2+e^{4\pi i/3}$ is a conjugate of $\sqrt 2+e^{2\pi i/3}$ over $\Bbb Q$.

Similarly as $\sqrt 2\notin \Bbb Q(e^{2\pi i/3})$, we get that $-\sqrt 2+e^{2\pi i/3}$ is a conjugate of $\sqrt 2+e^{2\pi i/3}$ over $\Bbb Q$.

Therefore $\sqrt 2+e^{2\pi i/3}$ has at least three conjugates over $\Bbb Q$, hence $[\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2+e^{2\pi i/3}):\Bbb Q]\geq 3$, however as $[\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2+e^{2\pi i/3}):\Bbb Q]\mid [\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2,e^{2\pi i/3}):\Bbb Q],$ we obtain $[\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2+e^{2\pi i/3}):\Bbb Q]=4$, i.e., $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2+e^{2\pi i/3})=\Bbb Q(\sqrt 2,e^{2\pi i/3})$.